# vb.Net - Looping through array returns error: expression of type which is not a collection type

Tags: .net, vb.net, arraylist

I am trying to get the index value of an array by using a for Each loop. 
I am making an error in my code that I do not know how to correct.

I cannot loop through the ArrayList because it is not a number.

```
Dim num As Integer = 0
If Not IsNothing(BreadCrumbIDs) Then
    For Each num In BreadCrumbIDs
        If num >= 0 And num <= 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(num)
        Else
            ' Do nothing
        End If
    Next
End If
```

I would like to loop throught the arrylist and obtain the index/ numeric values of it.

Let's say BreadCrumbsIds contains:

0 - shoes
1 - boots
2 - leather boots

I want to do something when the values are between 0 and 1 and something else when value is 2.

The Array List property code:

```
    Public Property BreadCrumbIDs() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return bcIDs
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ArrayList)
            bcIDs = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Show the definition for BreadCrumbIDs

Comment: If you don't have Integers in BreadCrumbIDs() then you will not have Integers in  BreadCrumbIDs().   Why are you using an ArrayList of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping the items in the list, loop the index.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To BreadCrumbIDs.Count-1
```

Then you can access the items with

```
BreadCrumbIDs(index)
```

If BreadCrumbIDs isn't a list of numbers, then I would suggest you change its name.

An other option could be to use the [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the list.

Comment: thank you the_lotus. attempting to use your example, gives me a syntax error on the = 0

Answer (score 0):

Another correct answer is:

If you are calling a function such as:

> ```
> Public Function Enumerate() As structPayments()
> ```

Using a for-loop such as

```
For Each item In invPay.Enumerate(InvoiceNo)
```

You will get the same exception in VS2015 because you are passing a variable/parameter to a function which does not accept any parameters.

Double check your function and make sure it is set to receive a parameter, in my case, it should be changed to:

```
Public Function Enumerate(InvoiceNo as String) As structPayments()
```